# When the date type data is reworked to JSON, what place does the format designation do?

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data

Sample application is being created with "Spring Boot + Spring Data + Cassandra" configuration.

Assume that the following data is stored

Result Query

```
cqlsh:keyspaceb> SELECT * FROM memobox where pkey1='a' and pkey2='b' ORDER BY id;

 pkey1 | pkey2 | id                                   | name     | date                     | memo
-------+-------+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------+----------------
     a |     b | ---- |   tanaka | 2016-12-13 00:00:00+0000 | greet message1
     a |     b | ---- | yamamoto | 2016-12-13 00:00:00+0000 | greet message2
```

Create Rest Web APP
The result of issuing curl is as follows.

```
$ curl http://localhost:8888/MemoBoxCassandra/api/memobox -i -XGET
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   265    0   265    0     0   1064      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1132HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 21 Dec 2016 01:21:43 GMT

[{"pkey1":"a","pkey2":"b","id":"----","name":"tanaka","memo":"greet message1","date":1481587200000},{"pkey1":"a","pkey2":"b","id":"f5ed41c0-c657-11e6-8db6-27bcd31c20cd","name":"yamamoto","memo":"greet message2","date":1481587200000}]
```

Here, "column" is "date", but I do not want the format I want.

On the Cassandra side it is a "timestamp" type.
On the Entity side of Java it is "java.util.Date" type.
The acquisition part of the Repository class is as follows.

```
package com.example.sb.repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.example.sb.entity.MemoBox;

@Repository
public interface MemoBoxRepository extends CassandraRepository<MemoBox> {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM memobox where pkey1='a' and pkey2='b' ORDER BY id")
    List<MemoBox> findAllOrderById();
}
```

Where should I specify the date format format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define the date format with ObjectMapper in configuration class.

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a z");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setDateFormat(df);
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

The above will impact all classes with Date property which are serialized and deserialized using jackson. If you want a particular class and property, you can use @JsonFormat in your POJO/entity like below.

```
public class Person {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
    private Date dateOfBirth;

    // other properties

    // setters and getters
}
```

Comment: I am very grateful to teach you a wonderful solution. Thank you